# how to install sails auth for manually configured mongoose ORM

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

Hi i removed waterline ORM from Sails JS and added mongoose, for that i followed the steps specified in the following link 
http://laurentschaffner.com/blog/from-waterline-to-mongoose-in-sails/ 
But now am facing issues in installing sails-auth module can anyone help me out please.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried to install sails-auth but I have successfully integrated Mongoose into Sails in a manner that I think is more friendly than the blog link you referenced. I created a gist here to help:

**Gist:** Adding Mongoose to Sails in a manner that binds promisified Mongoose functions to `Model.mongoose`, preserves blueprints (auto-generated action routes), and most importantly does not remove the Waterline ORM. Note: the code below uses ES2015 with the sails-babel hook.
https://gist.github.com/austinmao/83524cecd87ea1685b32